# Show that $r'(t)\times r''(t)=(\frac{ds}{dt})^3r'(s)\times r''(s)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

(This is a question in my homework, and i have no idea how to solve this.)

We define the curvature of a path by $||r''(s)||$, where $r(s)$ is the arc-length parametrization of the path. Given a path $r(t)$, we let $r(s)$ be its arc-length parametrization so that $s=\int^t_0||r'(\gamma)||d\gamma$.

(a) Show that $r'(t)\times r''(t)=(\frac{ds}{dt})^3r'(s)\times r''(s)$

(b) Hence, or otherwise, show that the curvature can be expressed in terms of t.
    Give the explicit form of the curvature function.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

First, by chain rule we have
$$r'(t)=\frac{ds}{dt}r'(s)\tag{1}\label{r'}$$
Applying chain rule again comes
$$r''(t)=\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}r'(s)+\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^2r''(s)\tag{2}\label{r''}$$
Now, we knoe that $v\times v=0$ for any vector, thus from (\ref{r'}) and (\ref{r''}), we have
$$r'(t)\times r''(t)=\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^3r'(s)\times r''(s).\tag{3}\label{vec}$$
This concludes item (a).

For item (b), note that
$$\frac{ds}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t\|r'(\gamma)\|\,d\gamma=\|r'(t)\|.$$

By other hand,
$$\|r'(s)\|=1\Rightarrow r'(s)\cdot r''(s)=0\Rightarrow r'(s)\perp r''(s).$$
From (\ref{vec}), we have
$$\|r'(t)\times r''(t)\|=\|r'(t)\|^3\|r''(s)\|.$$
Thus,
$$\kappa=\|r''(s)\|=\frac{\|r'(t)\times r''(t)\|}{\|r'(t)\|^3}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helps!